# Multiple WARs to Azure Web Application

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I'm currently on my final phase of my bachelor thesis, implementing a web application. Now I need to host it on Azure. I've an application.war with Angular Frontend in it and a services.war with the Java REST Calls. Both are packed through Maven.

When I deploy it from Github with GitHub Actions to Azure, I get the following Error:

> "Deployment Failed with Error: Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern: *.war. Please restrain the search pattern."

Do you have a tutorial or can help me how to setup the yml-file to deploy the application.war to ROOT and services.war to /services/...

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/**/target/*.war'

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'app-name'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }}
          package: '*.war'
```

Thank you very much!
Janick

Answer (score 1):

If you check this [Deploy Angular app to Azure App Service running Linux from GitHub](https://nicolgit.github.io/how-deploy-angular-app-to-azure-appservice-running-linux-from-github/), you will understand how to deploy an Angular single page application, from GitHub to Azure App Service.

In order to deploy to App Service using GitHub Actions we need a workflow file. **A workflow is defined by a YAML (.yml) file in the `/.github/workflows/` path in your repository**. This definition contains the various steps and parameters that make up the workflow.

Build and deploy a Java app to Azure using an Azure publish profile. The `publish-profile` input references the `AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE` secret that you created earlier.

```yaml
name: Java CI with Maven

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
      working-directory: my-app-path
    - name: Azure WebApp
      uses: Azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: my-app-name
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        package: my/target/*.war
```

For more information check this [Deploy to App Service using GitHub Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-github-actions?tabs=applevel) document from Microsoft. Also read this [Create Azure Web App and deploy using GitHub Actions](https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy#create-azure-web-app-and-deploy-using-github-actions) document from GitHub and check the example templates.